# How to represent rational numbers in memory?

Tags: binary, numbers, theory

There are three methods I know of to represent numbers in binary:

- Integers
- Fix point decimals (basically just integers divided by a constant)
- Floating point decimals (basically just integers divided/multiplied by a variable power of 2)

But none of these can represent numbers like 0.1 and 1/3 with full precision and without rounding errors.

I want to represent *any* rational number in memory - which different representations exist? What are their (dis)advantages (compared to the above)? And how do I calculate with them (+-*/)? What is their range, resolution and how to handle edge cases (extremely small/big/precise numbers)?

Some examples:

- 1/3
- 0.1
- 0.000001234
- 10^100
- 10^100+0.1
- 2/4

Answer (score 0):

A rational number Is defined as a number that can be represented as the ratio of two integers. Therefore, two integers of sufficient length must be stored to guarantee perfect precision of any rational number.

Usually, floats are used to store rational numbers, and the float is converted to a fraction only when being displayed.

Storing of irrational numbers, such as exact roots of prime numbers (rather than an approximate float), involves interpreted strings or computer algebraic systems.

Comment: I've removed `sqrt(2)` from the question, as it clearly doesn't fit.

Comment: Edited to remove explicit sqrt(2) reference.